# Regexp pattern for matching number groups separated by underscore

Tags: sql, regex

I have a mysql table where values stored in the following form:

```
5214-45_52
123-455_55_777_9999
4566-333_90_11_00
```

The values I need to search for are separated by underscore, after **"-"**.

So when I search for **"45"**, it must match `"5214-45_52"`, 
not `"123-455_55_777_9999"` nor `"4566-333_90_11_00"`

UPD: In other words, for string "5214-45_52", the regexp must search between 45 and 52

What regexp do I need to do this?

Comment: hey you just want to search for 2 numbers? why this can't be found `"123-455_55_777_9999"`? as is after - the patter"45"

Comment: no, position and length of search term can be different,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
-(.*_)?45(_|$)
```

---

**Description:**

- `-` literal hyphen
- `(.*_)?` Optional. Consume characters until the next underscore.
- `45` Change with the number you want
- `(_|$)` followed by another underscore or end of string

---

**Demo:**

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e21c2/6)

Comment: I just tried the pattern in mysql query and got error. "MySQL uses Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions, which is aimed at conformance with POSIX 1003.2". As I understand  +? and *? not allowed. :|